# Set uiview height by summary height of it content programmatically and add it to container with resize it

Tags: ios, swift, tabs, scrollview

There is product page. Here is many data - about it: photo, price, portion selector, button to add product in cart and many more. In the bottom (according to design layots) I must place view with tabs - (about and comments). "About" - contains product name, product description, few other items, "comments" contains UITableView with product comments and field for entering comment.

All these guys are not housing in standart screen - it is reason to use uiscrollview. I place all my views inside contentView of scroll view, add constraints and I get some free space at bottom of scrollview. I place here uiview - and add costraint bottom to bottom of superview and top to bottom of tabs (custom, because i need use design layouts), the lower view in scroll view. Consequently I get view which has no strong height constraints - I want use it as an container to place "about" and "comments" views depending on tab pressed. Height of about and comments is different for different products, therefore i must calculate height of about or comments page (depends on contains information) - at first, at second resize container for it. Is there way to do this?

I attach two images - design layout and my stroryboard screenschot where I add red selection of contatiner which I want to contains "about" or "comments".

[image]
[image]

Comment: Screenshot of the mockup or what do you want to achieve would be nice. Block of text is hard to visualize.

Comment: done, check please

Comment: As you can see tabs are "о продукте" and "комментарии". All under they must be placed in container view

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a great decision! )) I will use not a container and `.xib` created view, I will use `UITableView` in both cases - comments and product. And will set `scrollingDisabled = true` parameter to it. In that case tableview must resize by height and all be good, all what I need - create tableview datasourse and delegate to both cases. I will try it tomorrow, and tell you about results )

Comment: It works! I want to add some rep for myself answer, but it not good) Use that way if you will met same problem